# Awesomium - How/When Does Loading Occur

Tags: c#, awesomium

I am using Awesomium on .NET.

As it appears to me, setting WebView.Source to a webpage URL sets the Source property immediately, however, Awesomium waits for the thread that set WebView.Source to finish in order to begin loading the page. From observing my ResourceInterceptor, it appears that loading occurs on a separate thread (at least - ResourceInterceptor certainly does), yet that thread only begins executing when my 'Main' thread (the thread that owns the WebView and set WebView.Source) finishes its own tasks.

Is there a way to force a WebView to begin loading immediately? Maybe more specifically, can we force Awesomium to create a thread with the purpose of loading immediately after setting the WebView.Source property? Perhaps loading the WebCore (and subsequently, the WebView) in its own, dedicated thread straight from the start is the answer...

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe it's running on the UI thread and the other thread is blocking somehow. Is there a delay in a single-threaded test app?

Comment: My initial program upon discovering this issue was a single threaded app. Yes, a delay was present. In further research, I have determined that the ResourceInterceptor runs on the 'I/O' thread (according to Awesomium). At this time, I have 'forced' a WebView to run immediately by initializing the Awesomium WebCore in its own, dedicated thread.